# All of JQuery SlideToggle are opening when I clicked one toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

HTML

```
//FIRST TOGGLE
       <div class='dropdown-cus' type='button'>
            <div class='slidx'>
                <span>MENU<i class='fas fa-plus'></i></span>
            </div>
            <div  class='mfields hidden h-label'>
                <label >NAME:</label><input type='text' value=''  name='' class='re_'>
                <label >URL:</label><input type='text' value='LINK HERE'  name='' class='' >
                <input type='hidden' value='' class='input-text' name=''>
            </div>
        </div>
//SECOND TOGGLE
        <div class='dropdown-cus' type='button'>
            <div class='slidx'>
                <span>MENU<i class='fas fa-plus'></i></span>
            </div>
            <div  class='mfields hidden h-label'>
                <label >NAME:</label><input type='text' value=''  name='' class='re_'>
                <label >URL:</label><input type='text' value='LINK HERE'  name='' class='' >
                <input type='hidden' value='' class='input-text' name=''>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
        $(document).on('click','.slidx',function(){
            $(".mfields").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
        });
});
```

HERES THE JS FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/d2tcmqpo/2/

So I have two slide toggle please check the js fiddle so you can see, what I want to happen is if I click the first toggle then it will open, but the problem is when I click the first toggle the second toggle also opens.

I know I can solve this by using different class names per toggle. But I dont want that way, why? because if I will  have 100 toggles then I will have to code 100x of my current JQUERY code like this one.

```
$(document).on('click','.slidx_1',function(){
                    $(".mfields_1").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
                });
$(document).on('click','.slidx_2',function(){
                    $(".mfields_2").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
                });
$(document).on('click','.slidx_3',function(){
                    $(".mfields_3").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
                });
```

and so on.

I am thinking that maybe I should use the jquery `$(this)` but it is also doesnt work.

Is there any way to solve this? Or I have no choice but to use different class per toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a contextual lookup to find the slide related to the other element.  See the comments in the snippets below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $(document).on('click','.slidx',function(){
        //this selects all the mfields on the page, not just the one you want to slide.
        $(".mfields").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
    });
});



$(document).ready(function(){     
    $(document).on('click','.slidx',function(){
        //this version will find the parent dropdown-cus of the slidx and mfields,
        //and then find the mfields inside it, and only that one
        $(this).closest('.dropdown-cus').find(".mfields").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
    });
});
```

Comment: Almost there, but the problem now is when I click the first toggle it doesn't open Here's the JS Fiddle using your JQuery Code: http://jsfiddle.net/5ec2pvak/

Comment: @ICGDEVS it does if you comment out the first block of code, which is the old version.  http://jsfiddle.net/5ec2pvak/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $(document).on('click','.slidx',function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
    });
});
```

Comment: Take note that `next()` is only going to work so long as the element you want is the immediate sibling of the element.  In that aspect, it is more brittle than other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

First you have go to closest parent class and find your mfields

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){     
        $(document).on('click','.slidx',function(){
              $(this).closest('.dropdown-cus').find(".mfields").slideToggle( 'slow', function() {});
        });
      });
```

```css
.dropdown-cus{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-cus i{
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.dropdown-cus input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;

}
.h-label hr{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-cus span {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    transition: .5s;
    display: inline-block;
}
.h-label label {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dropdown-cus' type='button'>
            <div class='slidx'>
                <span>MENU<i class='fas fa-plus'></i></span>
            </div>
            <div  class='mfields hidden h-label'>
                <label >NAME:</label><input type='text' value=''  name='' class='re_'>
                <label >URL:</label><input type='text' value='LINK HERE'  name='' class='' >
                <input type='hidden' value='' class='input-text' name=''>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown-cus' type='button'>
            <div class='slidx'>
                <span>MENU<i class='fas fa-plus'></i></span>
            </div>
            <div  class='mfields hidden h-label'>
                <label >NAME:</label><input type='text' value=''  name='' class='re_'>
                <label >URL:</label><input type='text' value='LINK HERE'  name='' class='' >
                <input type='hidden' value='' class='input-text' name=''>
            </div>
        </div>
```